# Encryption and decryption of data using Angular BehaviorSubject()

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `BehaviorSubject()` to share data between Angular components and working as expected, but is it possible to securely (encryption and decryption using CryptoJs) sharing the data between components?

```
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class Store<T> {
    state$: Observable<T>;
    private _state$: BehaviorSubject<T>;

    protected constructor (initialState: T) {
        this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
        this.state$ = this._state$.asObservable();
    }

    get state (): T {
        return this._state$.getValue();
    }

    setState (nextState: T): void {
        this._state$.next(nextState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The components cannot communicate with each other if they are not part of the same application. Why would you add the extra complexity and performance penalty of encrypting the data?

Comment: @Octavian, Actually we are storing sensitive data like account information and sharing to other components with out calling the database.

Comment: Yes, you can do that it doesn't seem to be a problem. It just adds a layer b/w transportation. You can use web workers for that. I'm still not sure what exactly you wanted to know?

Comment: There is no point in encrypting the data on the frontend. Any client can see your code and any secret you would use to encrypt the data would be visible to everyone. The only reason you could have to encrypt data on you frontend is if you didn't trust the transport layer. But as both components live in the same application on your system I don't see the point.